# Running docker scan <image> returns an error on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, container-image

When I tried scanning local images, like the hello-world image, using `docker scan hello-world`, I get this error

```
docker: 'scan' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

My docker version is

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.2
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        2291f61
 Built:             Mon Dec 28 16:17:43 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

Comment: Thanks for making me discover that command. Unfortunately, according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/scan/), this feature is only availabe with Docker Destop Edge which is only available on windows and mac.

Comment: `docker scan` seems to be available for all/most environments now. I am very puzzled by the requirement of a docker hub login. Seems to make batch use pretty hard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plugin available:

**Requirement:** apt knows about the docker-repositories

This should be already fulfilled after following the install-guide at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Example:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list 
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
```

**Installation:**

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install docker-scan-plugin
```

**Running `docker scan`** will reveal more requirements:

- login to Docker Hub
- consent to access Snyk *(For more information search the web for `docker Snyk`.)*

```
$ docker scan hello-world
Docker Scan relies upon access to Snyk, a third party provider, do you consent to proceed using Snyk? (y/N)
y
failed to get DockerScanID: You need to be logged in to Docker Hub to use scan feature.
please login to Docker Hub using the Docker Login command
```